# Pattern for ulr (key=value&key=value) Java regex

Tags: java, regex

Want to know how to write the correct pattern regex of my url to match this :
key=value . 
2 pairs of key=value are Separated by « & » . 
Remove key if value is empty or null

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to remove empty parameters from your query string, you can use this regex `\w+=[^&]+` to match only key value pairs whose value part is non-empty. For e.g. if you have following string,

```
key1=value1&key2=value2&key3=&key4=value4
```

Then match only URLs using above regex and filter out rest. This Java code should help you,

```
String s = "key1=value1&key2=value2&key3=&key4=value4";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\w+=[^&]+");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
while(m.find()) {
    sb.append(m.group()).append("&");
}
System.out.println(sb.substring(0,sb.length()-1));
```

Prints this which has key3 value removed as it was empty,

```
key1=value1&key2=value2&key4=value4
```

Using Java8 streams, you can use this one liner code to achieve,

```
String s = "key1=value1&key2=value2&key3=&key4=value4";
String cleaned = Arrays.stream(s.split("&")).filter(x -> Pattern.matches("\\w+=[^&]+", x)).collect(Collectors.joining("&"));
System.out.println(cleaned);
```

Prints,

```
key1=value1&key2=value2&key4=value4
```